# Difference between ">& log" and ">& log&"

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I don't get what is the difference between all these commands in bash,

```
echo "Hello world" > log&
echo "Hello world" >& log
echo "Hello world" >& log&
```

What does each & do?

As far as I understand putting & at the end send the whole thing to the background. But what about the & after the > ?

Is there any advantage of writing

```
echo "Hello world" >& log&
```

instead of

```
echo "Hello world" > log&
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*The Bash Reference Manual*, §3.6.4 "Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error), the `>&` notation redirects standard output and standard error together.

In your specific example, I wouldn't expect `echo "Hello world"` to write anything to standard error, so the `&` doesn't really change anything; but if it *did* write things to both standard output and standard error, then `log` would end up with both.

Incidentally, per that same section, the equivalent notation `&>` is preferred over `>&` (presumably because `>&` is liable to be confused with notations like `>&1`, which does something quite different).

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks!
So basically the >& will send output en error to the log file, while >  will only send the output.
The last & (after the log) will do the things on the background. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's an accurate summary. (BTW, I'd second the advice to use `&>` rather than `>&` to avoid ambiguity).